# Automatic WIndows 7 Monitor Configurations

Tags: windows-7, windows, multiple-monitors

I'm working on an app on my phone that will automate many aspects of my home computer.  One such aspect is to switch between a `work` environment and a `home` environment.  The switch between the two primarily consists of changing monitor configurations (but also sound output if possible).

I have three monitors hooked up to my machine and in my `work` environment I want only monitors 1 & 2 to be active...but in the `home` environment I want monitor 3 to be the only active monitor.

I have been struggling with finding a way to automate this.  I've tried a few different tools including a few out of the NirSoft suite (MonitorInfoTool and MultiMonitorTool).  However each tool I find seems to have one serious flaw: the IDs either aren't unique (i.e. they change every time I change monitor configurations) or they are just flat out wrong.

MonitorInfoTool: Often times confuses two of the monitors, will state that monitor 1 and 3 are active when in reality, 2 and 3 are active (I know this isn't a desired configuration, but I was messing with it).

MultiMonitorTool: Doesn't have a unique indentifier.  The closest it has are the \\.\DISPLAYX identifiers which are seemingly randomly assigned when the monitor configuration is changed.  This tool also has a load/save monitor configuration feature, but I find that it often doesn't work.

After some research it seems that this is primarily an issue with Windows 7.  Microsoft simply didn't bother to create an easy way to identify monitors for other programs.

Has anyone been able to reliably switch between monitor configurations with Windows 7?  Has anyone been able to reliably map some kind of identifier for toggling (i.e. \\.\DISPLAYX id) to a human-readable (or semi-readable) name in Windows 7?